# NASM Assembly - having trouble displaying the results when running the program

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

I am trying to create a program that will first ask the user for an operator, ask for two numbers, and then display the operation as a whole. For example if the user chose "+", then "2", and then "3", the result should be "2 + 3 = 5"

I have managed to get the addition and subtraction to work correctly, but am having trouble figuring out how to get the multiplication and division parts to display correctly as the results would display numbers in the wrong locations or unrelated to the operation the user typed. Does anyone know how to fix it so that the results would be displayed correctly?

Here is the code:

```
%include "CPsub64.inc"

global main ;entry point for assembly

section .text
  main:
  mov rcx, 1 
  mov rdi, 1

loop2:

;display
  mov rax, 1
  mov rsi, message
  mov rdx, length
  syscall

;take input
  mov rdx, 255
  mov rcx, userInput1
  mov rbx, 0
  mov rax, 3
  int 80h

;display
  mov rax, 1
  mov rsi, message1
  mov rdx, length1
  syscall

;take input
  mov rdx, 255
  mov rcx, userInput2
  mov rbx, 0
  mov rax, 3
  int 80h

;convert to number
  mov rdx, userInput2
  mov rcx, 255
  call ParseInteger64
  mov r8, rax

;display
  mov rax, 1
  mov rsi, message2
  mov rdx, length2
  syscall

;take input
  mov rdx, 255
  mov rcx, userInput3
  mov rbx, 0
  mov rax, 3
  int 80h

;convert to number
  mov rdx, userInput3
  mov rcx, 255
  call ParseInteger64
  mov r9, rax

;Set up operator
  mov rsi, 0
  mov rsi, [userInput1]
  cmp sil, '+'
  je add

  mov rsi, 0
  mov rsi, [userInput1]
  cmp sil, '-'

  mov rsi, 0
  mov rsi, [userInput1]
  cmp sil, '*'

  mov rsi, 0
  mov rsi, [userInput1]
  cmp sil, '/'


; jump if addition
  cmp sil, '+'

; jump if subtraction
  cmp sil, '-'
  je subtract

; jump if multiplication
  cmp sil, '*'
  je multiply

; jump if division
  cmp sil, '/'
  je divide


;add
add:
  mov r10, r8
  add r10, r9

;display
  mov rax, r8
  call WriteInt
  syscall

;display
  mov rax, 1
  mov rsi, messageadd
  mov rdx, lengthadd
  syscall

;display
  mov rax, r9
  call WriteInt
  syscall

;display
  mov rax, 1
  mov rsi, messageeq
  mov rdx, lengtheq
  syscall

;display answer
  mov rax, r10
  call WriteInt
  jmp loop

;subtract
subtract:
  mov r10, r8
  sub r10, r9

;display
  mov rax, r8
  call WriteInt
  syscall

;display
  mov rax, 1
  mov rsi, messagesub
  mov rdx, lengthsub
  syscall

;display
  mov rax, r9
  call WriteInt
  syscall

;display
  mov rax, 1
  mov rsi, messageeq
  mov rdx, lengtheq
  syscall

;display answer
  mov rax, r10
  call WriteInt
  jmp loop

;multiply
multiply:
  mov rax, r8
  mov rax, r9
  mul rax

;display
  mov rax, r8
  call WriteInt
  syscall

;display
  mov rax, 1
  mov rsi, messagemul
  mov rdx, lengthmul
  syscall

;display
  mov rax, r9
  call WriteInt
  syscall

;display
  mov rax, 1
  mov rsi, messageeq
  mov rdx, lengtheq
  syscall

;display answer
  mov rax, r9
  call WriteInt
  jmp loop

;divide
divide:
  mov rdx, 0
  mov rax, r8
  mov rax, r9
  div rax

;display
  mov rax, r8
  call WriteInt
  syscall

;display
  mov rax, 1
  mov rsi, messagediv
  mov rdx, lengthdiv
  syscall

;display
  mov rax, r9
  call WriteInt
  syscall

;display
  mov rax, 1
  mov rsi, messageeq
  mov rdx, lengtheq
  syscall

;display answer
  mov rax, r9
  call WriteInt
  jmp loop


loop:


;blank
  mov rax, 1
  mov rsi, blank1
  mov rdx, lengthblank
  syscall


;blank
  mov rax, 1
  mov rsi, blank1
  mov rdx, lengthblank
  syscall

;display
  mov rax, 1
  mov rsi, message3
  mov rdx, length3
  syscall

;take input
  mov rdx, 255
  mov rcx, userInput4
  mov rbx, 0
  mov rax, 3
  int 80h

  mov rsi, 0
  mov rsi, [userInput4]
  cmp sil, 'y'

;jump if answer is yes
  cmp sil, 'y'
  je loop2

;blank
  mov rax, 1
  mov rsi, blank1
  mov rdx, lengthblank
  syscall

;exit
  mov rax, 60
  xor rdi, rdi
  syscall

section .data 
;addition message
  message: db "Enter the arithmetic operator (+ - * /):",0,0ah
  length: equ ($-message)

  message1: db "Please enter the 1st number",0,0ah
  length1: equ ($-message1)

  message2: db "Please enter the 2nd number",0,0ah
  length2: equ ($-message2)

  messageadd: db " + ",0
  lengthadd: equ ($-messageadd)

  messagesub: db " - ",0
  lengthsub: equ ($-messagesub)

  messagemul: db " * ",0
  lengthmul: equ ($-messagemul)

  messagediv: db " / ",0
  lengthdiv: equ ($-messagediv)

  messageeq: db " = ",0
  lengtheq: equ ($-messageeq)

  message3: db "Would you like to perform another operation? [y = yes / n = no]",0,0ah
  length3: equ ($-message3)

  blank1: db " ",0,0ah
  lengthblank: equ ($-blank1)


;user inputs
section .bss
userInput1: resb 255
userInput2: resb 255
userInput3: resb 255
userInput4: resb 255
```

Comment: You destroy the result after performing the division/multiplication. You should save the result temporarily just like you did with the addition.

Comment: I am having trouble figuring out how to do that though

Comment: Just copy `rax` into `r10` and back.